# Unable to bury job beanstalkd

Tags: node.js, beanstalkd

I'm using Beanstalkd via NodeJS (fivebeans client).

I cannot bury jobs, not even using telnet!

The answer to client.bury(jobID,priority) is always "NOT_FOUND". This is the case even when there is only 1 job in the system (inserted with Node) and I'm tryint to bury it directly, issuing a beanstalkd command through telnet:

bury 1 1000

But this returns "NOT_FOUND" too...

What could be wrong? stats-job() and delete work fine, so only bury has problems.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BURY can only be run after the job has been RESERVEd

```
peek-ready
FOUND 1 5
hello
bury 1 100
NOT_FOUND

reserve
RESERVED 1 5
hello

bury 1 100
BURIED
```